# Fancy URL for result page of instant jQuery search script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery. When the user queries, #**SEARCHTERM** is added onto my page URL. How can I make it so that my URL is something like #search/**SEARCHTERM**/1/?

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash=query;
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter `window.location.hash=query;` so it is `window.location.hash="search/" + query;`

You will also need to alter the function that reads it on page load to remove the "search/". Either use substring() or replace().